# How to recreate columns (whole grid) based on column structure provided from server in Kendo-Grid?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, calculated-columns

I have the default view configuration for grid which is initialized when page is loading. Above the grid i have the dropdown menu which is containing predefined available views (which are representing vissible columns in grid).

**Structure of predefined views is following:**

```
  "gridStructure" : {
    "columns" : [ {
      "id" : 6,
      "position" : 12,
      "title" : "Order archived",
      "locked" : false,
      "entityName" : null,
      "width" : "auto",
      "filterable" : {
        "cell" : {
          "dataTextField" : "archived",
          "operator" : "eq"
        }
      }
    }, {
      "id" : 7,
      "position" : 13,
      "title" : "Creation time",
      "locked" : false,
      "entityName" : null,
      "width" : "auto",
      "filterable" : {
        "cell" : {
          "dataTextField" : "creationTime",
          "operator" : "lte"
        }
      }
    } ]
  },
```

**Question is:**

Is possible destroy whole structure of the grid and set new to existing data which are holded in grid?

It means that i don't want to show/hide columns but recreate grid with new columns and old data.

How can i do it please?

Comment: Please see ["Should questions include “tags” in their titles?"](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles), where the consensus is "no, they should not"!

Comment: Destroy the old grid, create a new one with the proper columns and data, then append it to an element in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [setOptions](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#methods-setOptions) method of the Kendo UI grid.